# SQL growth percentage how to

Tags: sql, db-browser-sqlite

I know there are enough posts here about the percentage growth but nothing helped me.

I have a table with this columns:

```
    Retailer country, retailer_type, 
     product_type, product, year, revenue, 
     quantity, gross_margin
```

I have to find out to every single product how it developed over the years and how much it grows per percentage.

Can anyone help me? i can do that for every single product and year but its too much and I'm trying to write a query to do it all in one

```
SELECT product, year, SUM(revenue) AS sum_2012
FROM hallo
WHERE retailer_country LIKE 'United%States'
AND year = 2012
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: You need a GROUP BY!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add GROUP BY to your statement.

```
SELECT Country, year, SUM(Revenue) AS 'sumrev'
FROM hallo
GROUP BY [Country], [year]
```